# Generate HTML files from views using partials

Tags: html, express, compilation, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm working on email templates for Sendgrid and the more templates I get to do, the more tired I grow of doing always the same thing over and over, their text editor is shitty and it's not safe to store templates in their app as it can disappear with no chance of recovery (happened to me).

So I thought I might build a small project whose goal is to generate static HTML files from views. Each template I want to set up has a view and would be built using components isolated in partial files.

So far I have this kind of structure:

```
dist/
  mail-template-1.html
  mail-template-2.html
src/
  partials/
    components/
      header.hbs
      illustration.hbs
      legal.hbs
      footer.hbs
    layout/
      before-content.hbs
      after-content.hbs
   views/
     mail-template-1.hbs
     mail-template-2.hbs
```

Content of a view template:

```
{{> layout/before-content}}
{{> components/header}}
{{> components/illustration}}
{{> components/legal}}
{{> components/footer}}
{{> layout/after-content}}
```

Handlebars use is not mandatory, started with that cause I thought it would fit the use. I guess it can also be useful to render in browser with a node/express server for dev, before building the html at the end.

So How would you do that ? I'm more of a HTML CSS guy, never done this kind of thing before.
The goal would be to modify any template view file, run a script (or a watcher if no browser rendering implemented) for it to get the content of all those partials and concatenate their content into an HTML file in the dist folder.
Have you got any ideas ? Any example of this kind of use ?
Thanks for the help

Comment: So you've got templates... What did you try and do with them that didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

I send out email using templates. Create tax invoices with templates too.

Nodejs, handlebars, mongodb (if you need a database). Lots of tutorials on youtube.

My order emails, I have template for email signature, email body body, and template tax invoices for different countries.